# Reloadable custom config for ASP.NET Core app hosted on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, kudu

I need to expose few simple configuration options for my website, that should be easy to change, without requiring recompilation or restarting the app. I'd also like the options to be cached in the app, but they should refresh when the config is changed (or at least every few minutes). My website is an ASP.NET Core MVC app, which runs on Azure App Service and is deployed by pushing to a git repository and then rebuilt using Kudu.

I was thinking about using Configuration with an EF provider, but it requires quite a bit of work to support reloading of the config when the data is changed.

I noticed that JSON config provider has "reloadOnChange" option, so this seems like a good candidate. However, I'm not sure where I should put the JSON file on the Azure App Service environment so it's easily readable by the app, shared across all instances and persistent between deploys. I know that the "d:\home" folder is shared and persistent. The wwwroot is inside of it, but I'm afraid that the file might get deleted at some point when the app is redeployed. So I'd like to put it in one of the parent folders, but how do I access the home folder from the C# code? I'm assuming I shouldn't just hardcode the "d:\home" path.

I'm also very keen to hear about any alternative ways to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you do not need to worry that it will delete `appsetting.json` file when you redeployed. If you change your configurations, it will **override** the json file.

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
           .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .Build();
```

**Note**: When you publish the app, **remember do not click** "`Remove additional files at destination`".

Also, if you want to set the `appsetting.json` in home folder, you could use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Home");` which is equal to "D:\home".

And if you set like this, you need to set `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to **distinguish your environment is azure or local**.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I deploy via pushing to git repository and then kudu rebuilds the project on the server on each deploy. Do you know it this way of deploying guarantees the file not to be deleted?

Comment: No matter it will delete or override, the final result is the same, all the settings are the latest. And I think you do not need to set the json file to home folder, when it changed, it will reload to the webapp.

Comment: I't like to store some constants in the JSON file and I can't lose it, because then defaults would be used. I guess the answer is to store the file in the home folder and reference to it using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Home").